# Upload files through Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I'm about to attempt to upload several files through a Google Chrome Extension.

Instead of pressing the Upload button on the webpage and load each file one by one I want to automate it.

How should I go about this? Is it as simple as detecting the script inside the DOM responsible with uploading, changing the file_to_upload string from the scipt with a filename on my computer and injecting the new script and execute it ?

Comment: I guess you cannot replace the filename of an input element of type `file` as it would be one hell of a security risk. The user always has to select files manually

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23656902/934239