# File upload with Javascript in chrome or firefox extension without user intervention

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I've managed to get the element of a button inside a a webpage . I know its ID , its class , etc ; I even managed to trigger the click event from within a content script from a Google Chrome extension . The button is inside a Google webpage.

There's a Browse button though that opens up a openDialog window and prompts the user to chose a certain file for uploading. How can I go on automating this upload without prompting the user for the file? I just want to feed it the string from the content script and the webpage takes it from there.

Is there a solution for this in Google Chrome, Firefox?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are uploading from the clients computer, you can't. Its a security feature of file.upload. If you examine the path to the uploaded file, you'll notice c://fakepath/xxxxx this is to prevent applications finding out file structure on the clients computer.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

Comment: Yes it's uploaded from the client's computer. There must be a solution for this ... is there?

Comment: no fortunately not, imagine you could search a clients computer for files that contain "bank details", "passwords" etc. But what are you trying to upload?

Comment: So I guess the only solution would be to create a standalone app in JAVA, .NET for the client to use in order to upload the file without the browser. Any idea how one might go about this?

Comment: yes, try -http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html , again it depends on what you are using it for, how do you know the file will exist? why do you need it uploaded? will the client be happy to install the app for this purpose?

Comment: Firefox extensions can access the local filesystem with the same privileges as the browser.

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox add-ons (well, in the privileged parts, i.e. not SDK page-mods and so on), you can construct a file object you could use with the regular HTML5 stuff (`XMLHttpRequest`, `FormData` ;)) directly via [the `File` "constructor"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extensions/Using_the_DOM_File_API_in_chrome_code):

```
var file = File("path/to/some/file");
```

When it comes to Chrome you're out of luck as @David already correctly pointed out in the other answer.

*Edit 1*:
Actually, when it comes to chrome it might be possible to request [a `file://*` permission](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns), have the user opt-in explicitly, and then use [`xhr`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr) etc. to first retrieve the file as a blob and then upload the blob with another `xhr`. Haven't tested this, though.